# What are the possible positions can be used with the background package?

Tags: positioning, backgrounds

I can't find the possible positions documented anywhere. I am looking for positions like `current page.south west`, etc. Anyone knows where I can find complete list of the possible positions?

The problem I am having is that I am using the [`background`](http://ctan.org/pkg/background) package and the `\SetBgPosition` takes a position. I am having hard time figuring out how to place the text in the center bottom of the page.

Comment: Before creating a new tag (here: {positions}), please check if the autocompletion feature suggest an existing tag that might be appropriate (here: {positioning}).

Comment: the options are exactly the same as for nodes in `PGF/TikZ`. You can use `\SetBgAngle{0}`
`\SetBgAnchor{above}`
`\SetBgPosition{current page.south}` to place the text in the bottom center; further adjustments can be done by using `\SetBgHshift{<value>}` and `\SetBgVshift{<value>}` (for horizontal and vertical shifting, respectively).

Comment: The package also offers the `bottom` package option to place the material in the bottom center: `\usepackage[bottom]{background}`. (This option will change to `placement=bottom` in the next version of the package.)

Answer (score 4):

The *positions* you ask for seem to be *coordinates*. Any form of coordinates should be allowed, e.g. `(x,y)` or `(node.anchor)`. The `current page.south west` example you mention is the *anchor* `south west` of the *node* `current page`. This node is a special `rectangle` node created by PGF/TikZ.

See section 13 *Specifying Coordinates* on page 123 of the v2.10 `pgfmanual` for a general description of coodiantes.

A description of all anchors can be found in section 48 *Shape Library* on page 419, even for the default shapes which do not require this library.

The `current page` node is described in section 75.4 *Special Nodes* on page 624.